# OpenMP tasks and Thread creation

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, task, openmp

I want to get IDs of different threads in an OpenMP program. Why I get the same thread ID for the below code?

```
#pragma omp task untied
     id1 = omp_get_thread_num(); printf("TID:%d\n",id1);
     foo_par(A);
#pragma omp task untied
     id2 = omp_get_thread_num(); printf("TID:%d\n",id2);
     foo_par(B);
 ....
```

Why I get '0' for both `id1` and `id2`?

Comment: Please try to read [OpenMP specifications](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1.pdf), section 2.7: you will notice that the premise to your question "_As far As I know, for every task in OpenMP a thread is created_" is simply not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code:

```
#pragma omp task untied
     id1 = omp_get_thread_num(); printf("TID:%d\n",id1);
     foo_par(A);
#pragma omp task untied
     id2 = omp_get_thread_num(); printf("TID:%d\n",id2);
     foo_par(B);
```

Since, you are not using `{}` only this instruction `omp_get_thread_num();` will became a task.

Btw, remember that the `task pragma` is available since `OpenMP 3.0`, so if your GCC is an older version that 4.4, the task directives will be ignored.

Try the following:

```
#pragma omp parallel region
{
  #pragma omp single
  {
   #pragma omp task untied
   {
     id1 = omp_get_thread_num(); printf("TID:%d\n",id1);
     foo_par(A);
   }

   #pragma omp task untied
   {
     id2 = omp_get_thread_num(); printf("TID:%d\n",id2);
     foo_par(B);
   }
 }
}
```

The single construct is needed so that tasks would be created by one thread only. Otherwise, 
each task would get created N times (N == number of threads).

Note that, if one thread 'X' is able to finish their work and request for another task in the pool it may start before another thread in the team. In another words, even if you have defined 2 different task (for example), the tasks might be executed by the same thread.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#pragma omp task untied
if (omp_get_thread_num() == 1)
  foo_par(A);
else
  foo_par(B);
```

GDB can be used to [debug a program with multiple threads](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html#Threads). Use this to step through your code to know the values of `omp_get_thread_num()` for each thread; although, it will be apparent while debugging.